# Need Help to open ftp server and login with batch

Tags: batch-file, ftp, cmd, echo, pipe

I need to make a batch file which opens my ftp server automatically,How do i  automatically input user name and password to the ftp username and password prompt.I have tried to use
echo username|ftp ipadress,but it is taking the input for both user name and password. So I need help to create a batch file, which automatically logins as "user" and password "pass"

Comment: What script are you using now, and what do you mean by 'open' it? Do you have a specific client you'd like to use? It *is* possible (although not ideal) to include the username/pass in the URL string itself: `ftp://username:password@hostname/`.

Comment: thanks,but i need to login through command prompt

Comment: First google match? http://www.dostips.com/DtTipsFtpBatchScript.php

Comment: [Creating a Windows FTP script](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch001249.htm). Microsoft: [How to script ftp commands](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/555976).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before you use the following script, please remember that the FTP protocol
doesn't allow encryptions, the authentication process and the data transitions.

1. Create a new text file with the following text:

   ```
   open "myservername/serverip"
   "%username%"
   "password"
   cd /upload
   bin
   hash
   put/get "filename.cab"
   bye
   ```

   *Note: Please choose the correct ftp commands to allow the script to work.*
2. Save the file as `runftp.txt` (For example).
3. Run the command: `c:\windows\system32\ftp.exe -s:runftp.txt`

**SOURCE:** http://support.microsoft.com/kb/555976